# Retrieve aws s3 bucket policy in json pretty format

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Retrieving AWS S3 bucket policy in pretty json format.

```
aws \
--profile AWS_PROFILE  \
s3api get-bucket-policy \
--bucket AWS_S3_BUCKET \
--query Policy --output text | jq .
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following:

```
aws s3api get-bucket-policy \
    --bucket <AWS_S3_BUCKET> \
    --query Policy --output text --profile la | jq
```

Example output:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
    }
  ]
}
```